# iSCSI - Unable to mount external disk on target

Tags: debian, mount, iscsi

I use targetcli-fb package

My target is configured on a computer with installed Debian.

Initiator is configured on Virtual Debian System, I use VirtualBox for virtualisation.

I log in to target from initiator. I mount disk

```
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
```

I then create some trash files on `/mnt`

```
nano test.txt

mkdir test
```

And now I want check `/dev/sdb1` on target. I can't mount `/dev/sdb1` to `/mnt` on target. I also tried to mount it before logging from initiator.

I tried to check processess binded to it, but I ask here how to check them. Which information I need deliver to get answer?

How to mount this `/dev/sdb1` on target and check what is stored on it? Or how check what is on this disk?

> mount: /dev/sdb1 is already mounted or /mnt busy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iSCSI is not a file sharing protocol but a block device sharing protocol: Without some serious tricking (a cluster file system) it is not possible to mount the same iSCSI disk on two initiators.

To mount it on an initiator and the target runs into the additional problem, that the target software will exclusivly lock the disk and so prevent a local mount.

If you want to share a disk in the sense of being able to access it from both operating systems at the same time, use a file sharing protocol.

**EDIT**

If you want to mount the disk on the target side, stop the iSCSI service  - this will release the lock.

You can of course force the concurrent use of the disk (by logging into the iSCSI target from the target-sided OS), but if you mount the block device on both sides without using a proper cluster file system, you will lose data. Seriously.

Comment: 1) So I shouldn't mount it on target?
2) I don't see the storage from server/target level?
3) Can I log in to target from target? (to see what is on disk)

Comment: To make it short: You can always use a shared block device **only on one OS at the time** without real clustering software.

Comment: See my edit: Unmount from the initator, log out from initiator, stop iSCSI service, then mount on target.